# SwiftUI Rectangle suddenly transforms into RoundedRectangle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have just started learning SwiftUI and was playing around with views and animations, I wanted to make controller kinda like apple has in control center for volume or brightness. But i found funny little thing and i don't really know what to do with that.

```
struct DragControler: View {
    @GestureState var fillPercentGS : Double = 0.5
    @State var fillPercent = 0.5
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{

            Rectangle()
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Rectangle().foregroundColor(.red) //these rects
                    Rectangle().foregroundColor(.green).frame(height: geometry.size.height * CGFloat(self.fillPercent))
                }.gesture(DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .local).updating(self.$fillPercentGS, body: { (value, state, transaction) in
                    state =  Double(value.location.y/geometry.size.height)

                }).onChanged({ (value) in
                    self.fillPercent = max(0, min(1 - Double(value.location.y/geometry.size.height), 1))
                }))
            }
            Text("\(fillPercent)").foregroundColor(.white)
            }.cornerRadius(50).aspectRatio(1/4, contentMode: .fit).padding()
    }
}
```

[GIF when one of rects fills entire view it becomes rounded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4G82.gif)

So as you can see on the gif, when i drag it all the way to the top or bottom Rectangles which are clearly said to be Rectangles in code become rounded rectangles

So, why is it happening? I have tried to replace .cornerRadius() modifier with clipShape(RoundedRect(...)) but it doesn’t help. 
But it i've found that it helps to explicitly set corner radius of these Rectangles to zero.

```
Rectangle().cornerRadius(0).foregroundColor(.red)
Rectangle().cornerRadius(0).foregroundColor(...)
```

My guess is that it is kinda optimisation swiftUI does on the background

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me, but there is an easy fix.  Simply explicitly set the corner radius of your green rectangle to 0:

```
Rectangle().foregroundColor(.green).frame(height: geometry.size.height * CGFloat(self.fillPercent)).cornerRadius(0)
```